# How to validate a part of string using Unicode Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, unicode

Example string : **https://test-welcome123.com/ablcv#$2**
I want to validate only **https://test-welcome.com** this part. **/ablcv#$2** this part I don't want to validate.
Requirement :

1. URL (https://test-welcome123.com) should be lower case alphabet, number, dot(.) and hyphen(-).
2. after slash(/) it can be anything.

I am using Unicode regular expression to validate the string.
I am able to do the validation the URL. But could not understand how to avoid the validation the string after slash(/).

```
^(https://)(((([\p{Ll}\p{N}]|[\p{Ll}\p{N}][\p{Ll}\p{N}\-]*[\p{Ll}\p{N}])\.)*([\p{Ll}\p{N}]|[\p{Ll}\p{N}][\p{Ll}\p{N}\-]*[\p{Ll}\p{N}])))+$
```

I need to avoid the validation after enter the URL. how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```cs
^https://[\p{Ll}\p{N}]+(?:[-.][\p{Ll}\p{N}]+)*/.*
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `https://`  - a protocol substring with `://`
- `[\p{Ll}\p{N}]+` - one or more letters or digits
- `(?:[-.][\p{Ll}\p{N}]+)*` - zero or more repetitions of:

  - `[-.]`  - a `-` or .` chars
  - `[\p{Ll}\p{N}]+` - one or more letters or digits
- `/` - a `/` char
- `.*` - the rest of the line (string).

Comment: can you please tell me how to validate the string which has ;@#. String will be invalid If those special characters are there.

Comment: @DebasishHalder A string that has no `;@#`? `^[^;@#]*$`.